# How does one access this hash from an ActiveRecord class in the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple hash I created to make it easier to do dictionary type lookups. For instance:

```
class Numbers < ActiveRecord::Base

   MY_TYPES {
      one: => 1,
      two: => 2
   }

end
```

Is it not possible in the rails console to access this hash via `Numbers.MY_TYPES[:one]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Numbers::MY_TYPES[:one]
```

Why: MY_TYPES is not a method of class Numbers. It is a constant. So you use Numbers::MY_TYPES as the reference